# Using n_distinct in dplyr with missing values as part of summarise

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a summary table showing the number of unique values in a vector within a data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, NA))
```

The na_rm argument works when summarise isn't used:

```
n_distinct(df$x)
n_distinct(df$x, na_rm = T)
```

But when used as part of summarise it doesn't:

```
summarise(df, freq = n_distinct(x))
summarise(df, freq = n_distinct(x, na_rm = T))
```

I have a solution:

```
summarise(df, freq = length(unique(x)))
summarise(df, freq = length(unique(x[complete.cases(x)])))
```

But I wanted to know why n_distinct isn't working as it's faster and more concise. Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: library(dplyr) is of course needed too

Comment: Try writing out `TRUE`, rather than just `T` (which you should be doing anyway).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that could be an issue

Comment: Well, I think it might be fair to say that it's an oversight in how dplyr is handling all it's special evaluation, but it's also as good a time as any to break yourself of the habit of writing just `T` and `F`, which can be overwritten.